# Вытащить src из ImageView или передать bitmap?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Есть `ActivityForResult` с несколькими известными иконками из `R.mipmap` (т.е. в `layout.xml` в `ImageView` в параметре `src="@mipmap/ic_category_auto"`), мне надо после выбора иконки показать в исходном активити.
Гуглю весь вечер - не могу найти как автоматизировать этот процесс.
Ладно если выбираешь из 4-х картинок, то можно обойтись:

`if (v.getId() == R.id.imgeview1) "тогда putExtra(R.mipmap....)";`

А если их будет динамически подгружаемое количество

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чём задача и в чём проблема. У вас там список ImageView и вам надо узнать какие из них были нажаты?.. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Не, не так. У меня есть список ImageView в ActivityForResult, по нажатию на ImageView мне надо в исходном активити отобразить такое же изображение как и в нажатом ImageView.src="@mipmap/example."

Answer (score 2):

Если вы создаете ваши `ImageView` динамически, то вам никто не мешает в момент создания запоминать, какой именно ресурс был вставлен в какой именно `ImageView`. Для этого можете, например, записывать это все в `Map<ImageView, Integer>`, где ключами будут `ImageView`, а значениями - вставленные в них ресурсы.
Если не динамически, то вы можете достать из ImageView изображение(`Drawable`).

```
imageView.getDrawable();
```

Если вы уверены, что там будут только битмепы, никаких XML Drawable, То можете достать и сам битмеп:

```
((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap()
```

Comment: @АлексейБуров, просто далеко не факт, что изображение установлено в `ImageVIew` из ресурсов. Поэтому такого метода нет.

Comment: @АлексейБуров, нет, Bitmap в parcable вы скорее всего не запихнете. Вы можете сохранять изображение в файл, и передавать путь к этому файлу, например.

Comment: Идеальным вариантом конечно было бы что-то вроде этого:  
`int imgID = myImageView.getSrc();`  
Либо может есть что-то типа:  
`int imgID = myImageView.getAttribute("src");`  

Но если можно только по вашему варианту, то надо передать этот Drawable или Bitmap в другое активити. Это можно сделать как нибудь попроще чем через parcelabel?
У меня пока с ним проблемы (

PS: извините, не могу разобраться как перевод строки в коментах ставить (пробовал и два пробела и <br/> - нифига)

Comment: @АлексейБуров, не переносятся строки в комментарияк...

Comment: Спс, буду знать)   Подскажи пожалуйста, если я спокойно работал через drawable, т.е. `Drawable drw = imageView.getDrawable(); imageView2.setDrawable(drw);` - все отлично срабатывает. Зачем тогда получать bitmap?

Comment: @АлексейБуров, а откуда же я знаю, зачем вам нужен Bitmap? Это же вы его поросили (см. заголовок вашего вопроса)

Comment: Точно)) Да в каком-то примере вычитал. А drawable можно запихнуть в parcelable? Как я понял в parcalable можно впихнуть всё что угодно, ведь он работает  с байтами. Но вот организовать это трабла для чайника..

Comment: @АлексейБуров, в `Parcelable` можно впихнуть почти что угодно. Проблема в том ,что через `Bundle` можно передать ограниченный объем данных. И изображение туда влезет только очень маленькое.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```